# Lambda Expression use case and connection with Functional Interface

Tags: java, java-8

I am currently learning about Lambda expressions in Java. As per my understanding it is a block of code that we can pass around so that it can be executed later. But I cannot think of examples when we want to execute the code later.

What are various scenarios where this is useful? Also what is the connection between Lambda Expression and Functional interface?

Comment: when you pass *any* object, you are passing some code that can be invoked later :) i.e. its methods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `Lambda expression` is used when we want to execute a block of code later, once or multiple times. The actual point of using it is `deferred execution` and there are many reasons for executing code later, such as:

1. We want to run the code in separate thread.
2. We want to run the code multiple times.
3. We want to run it at a specific point in an algorithm e.g. comparison operation while sorting.
4. We want to run the code when some event happens e.g on click of a link etc.
5. We want to run it only when necessary etc.

**Connection between Lambda Expression and Functional Interface**

A `Functional interface` is an interface which has only one abtract method (though it can have multiple default methods). We can supply a lambda expression whenever an object of an Functional Interafce is expected. Consider an example where we
want to execute some action n times.

```
execute(n, () -> System.out.println("Java Rocks"));
```

To accept the lambda the second parameter of the method signature must be Functional Interface and in the above example we can use e.g Runnable.

```
public static void execute(int n, Runnable action) {
     for(int counter = 0; counter < n; counter ++) {
           action.run();
     }
}
```

The point to note here is that the Lambda Expression is executed when `action.run()` is called. You can read more about Lambda Expression [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

Comment: To elaborate on the link between them: `() -> System.out.println("Java Rocks")` in this context is (almost) shorthand for `new Runnable() {public void run() {System.out.println("Java Rocks");}}`. ("Almost" because there are subtle differences)